# Фиксация размеров Layout при анимации

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Есть ConstraintLayout, в котором расположено несколько элементов. С помощью нескольких ConstraintSet.applyTo я запускаю анимацию на изменение положения элементов в лайауте. Разных "состояний" может быть несколько, и в каждом из них итоговая высота ConstraintLayout может отличаться, в виду установки высоты в wrap_content. Для адекватности отображение я хочу сделать высоту этого лайаута фиксированной, чтобы при анимации размеры не менялись и элементам вне этого лайаута не приходилось адаптироваться. Возник вопрос как это сделать. Пока придумал только 2 варианта.

1) Своими силами определить какое состояние самое высокое и воткнуть вьюшки-"распорки". Пример: в состоянии А имеется 2 текстВью друг над другом, в состоянии б только одно из них видимо. Чтобы высота не зменилось в разметку Б добавляем два невидимых текстВью друг над другом, которые не дадут уменьшить высоту лайаута.

2) При создании вьюшки прогонять ее по всем состояниям, запоминать полученные высоты и фиксировать наибольшую.

Оба решения весьма костыльные. Есть какие-то более элегантные решения?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно менять только положение элементов (View), тогда я советую вам обратить внимание на Transition: https://habr.com/ru/post/243363/. Очень всё вкусненько и простенько (анимация не только перемещений). И ещё загляните сюда: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/

Comment: Абсолютно верно, именно о Transition речь) Только я вместо сцен использую CostraintSet, но сути это не меняет. Проблема в том, что мой лайаут имеет высоту wrap_content, и от перехода от одного сета/сцены к другому эта высота меняется. У меня несколько таких элементов подряд, и это смотрится не очень хорошо. Впорос как избежать измения высоты